# Cannot localize images in Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, internationalization

I was reading the iOS 8 series from RayWenderlich.com website.

I came to the localization and internationalization. Read every single bit of it but I could not succeed on localizing images. (I did localized strings with no errors :) )

Here is what I have done:
1- Created a project of Single View Application

2- Placed an UIImageView on the Sotryboard by drag and drop.

3- Added my image to my project (back.png).

4- Assigned my UIImageView to that image (back.png).

Now is the steps for localization:

1- Go to project navigator and select the project.

2- Under localization, "Use Base Internationalization" us checked by default.

3- I added Arabic language.

4- Localized Storyboard files and its .strings and my image (back.png)

I have two image files English and Arabic versions. Each file on its respective folder. See screenshot.

[image]

When I run my app on the simulator which has Arabic language installed and selected. My imageView still displays the English version of the image.

I tried to use ar_SA (Arabic, Saudi Arabia) but still same issue. My image is displayed in English.

I have my simulator reset, and I have deleted derived files form library/dev.../xcode... But my app does not care about the Arabic version of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to localize app according to system language it is not happen in iOS 8 because it is a bug.
you can be sure from this point by trying to run the code in the following link.

https://github.com/EmanRezk/Localize.git

change simulator language to arabic in 
iphone5s (7.0) then run app you will see the arabic image.
iphone5s (8.1) then run app you will see the english image.

I advice you to localize app according to app language not the system language.